# Counting - possible schedules for dinner

Tags: combinatorics

Fred is planning to go out to dinner each night of a certain week, Monday through Friday, with each dinner being at one of his ten favorite restaurants. How many possibilities are there for Fred's schedule of dinners for that Monday through Friday, if Fred is willing to eat at the same restaurant more than once, but is not willing to eat at the same place twice in a row (or more)?

I think it should be 10*9*9*9*9. Is this correct and is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. For every choice, you cannot choose the one that you chose before. The base case is that you could choose any restaurant as your first choice, so this becomes $$ 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 9 \cdot 9 \cdot 9 $$